# how to step over through next iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, math, arithmetic-expressions

```
store_array = list()
test_case = input()
for i in range(int(test_case)) :
    number1 = input()
    number2 = input()
    store_array.append(int(number1))
    store_array.append(int(number2))

j=0
def add(x,y):
    for j in store_array:
        return x + y 
        j=j+1       
print(add(store_array[j],store_array[j+1]))
```

what I ve done so far?

testcase - > 2

2
2
3
3

these values are stored in the list under the name store_array

it executes and print the first two values 2 2 and the output 4 will be displayed

how can i step over to next two values and print the consecutives other two input?

Comment: So you want to step forward every other value correct? Why not just increment your iterator by 2 instead of one?

Comment: Tried but doesn't make sense

Comment: Please explain better what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: your indentation and use of return and incrementation of j all don't make much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to step forward every other value. Try this and see if it helps.

Simply change:

```
j=0
def add(x,y):
    for j in store_array:
        return x + y 
        j=j+1  
print(add(store_array[j], store_array[j+1]))
```

To this:

```
def add(x):
    for j in range(0, len(store_array) -1, 2):
        print(x[j] + x[j+1])      

print(add(store_array))
```

This may have the exact behavior you're looking for but it's a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for v your answer, but doesn't make sense

Comment: @Thiyagu Can you explain more? What do you mean it doesn't make sense?

Comment: It remains the same, even updating j = j + 2,  and first two values gets printed and the remaining stayed at their place

Comment: @Thiyagu My bad, I misinterpreted what you were trying to do. I edited my answer so it should be a good place to start but unfortunately I don't entirely understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: don't change the value of the iterating variable, that's just plain confusing. Instead, use the parameters of `range` to go 2 by 2

Comment: @njzk2 updated my answer with your suggestion. I was just trying to keep it in the style of the answer to retain clarity for the question asker.

Answer (score 0):

Take into consideration the "continue" statement.
It makes the loop skipping some iteration.

```
for i in range(6):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        continue
    print(i)
```

it will skip all the values that are even.

Comment: yes, but the author is probably not familiar with the idea of "continue"